# How long is the duration of exposure on an iPhone 6 in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, camera, iphone

How long is the exposure (not the range) duration on an iPhone 6 camera? I am running iOS 8.

Comment: It will depend on the light conditions on each picture. Are you asking about the maximum / minimum exposure possible?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the lighting conditions the exposure time is between 1/50000 to 1/15 seconds. However with camera apps (other than the default one) you can achieve much longer exposure times (as long as you want).

Comment: why max exposure duration on iPhone 6 smaller than iPhone 5 ?
AND
can increase exposure duration more than 1 second .

Comment: The durations I mentioned apply only for the default camera app. As I said other camera apps can control the exposure time. I assume that the max exposure time on iPhone 6 is smaller because it has a bigger camera pixels so Apple decided to shorten the time in order to achieve sharper photos.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum exposure time on the iPhone 6 is 1/2 second, reduced to 1/3 on the 6s. Even third-party camera apps can't take longer exposures. They can take multiple exposures and merge them, but not a single exposure longer than the above numbers.